# C# if statement evaluating to true when String.IsNullOrEmpty is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, behavior

I have a static method in a helper class that emails administrators to notify them of errors. Before emailing, I check to see if the necessary email addresses have been provided in web.config.

When the first String.IsNullOrEmpty runs, the statement following the if is skipped. However, the statement following the second if executes. In

In both cases, I'm able to examine the respective email variable in the Visual Studio debugger, and I can verify that each variable has an actual email address in it. I have also debugged with no watches set, just to ensure that the watches weren't having an effect.

Additionally, I have tried placing { } around each statement that follows an if, but that didn't change the behavior.

If I change the order of these if statements, the same thing occurs; the first throw is skipped, but the second throw executes.

While writing this, I noticed that moving the Console.WriteLine down below the ifs causes everything to work as intended. I'm still curious, though, as to why this would occur if I leave the code as I have posted below. It would be nice to be able to avoid this issue in the future!

The method:

```
public static bool NotifyAdmin(string subject, Exception e, string additionalInfo = "")
{
  String message = String.Format("Exception Message: {0}\n\nStackTrace:\n{1}\n\nAdditional Info:\n{2}", e.Message, e.StackTrace, additionalInfo);

  Console.WriteLine(message);

  String adminEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminEmail"];
  String programEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["programEmail"];

  // Check to ensure that the necessary app settings have been provided
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminEmail))
    throw new Exception("adminEmail not specified in AppSettings.");

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(programEmail))
    throw new Exception("programEmail not specified in AppSettings.");

  try
  ...
}
```

### UPDATE 1:

The information stored in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="adminEmail" value="person1@company.com;person2@company.com"/>
    <add key="programEmail" value="program@company.com"/>
  </appSettings>
  ...
```

### UPDATE 2:

Additionally, I've removed the `try..catch` block, leaving the method ending like this, and it works fine:

```
  ...
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(programEmail))
    throw new Exception("programEmail not specified in AppSettings.");

  return true;
}
```

But if I try a minimal case, the second `throw` still occurs:

```
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(programEmail))
    throw new Exception("programEmail not specified in AppSettings.");

  try
  {
    message = "";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }

  return true;
}
```

### UPDATE 3:

I've tried opening this website in VS Express 2013 for Web (I've been using 2012 Pro), and still I get the same result.

I can also have the second `if` statement done like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(programEmail))
{
  message = "";
  throw new Exception("programEmail not specified in AppSettings.");
  message = "something else";
}
```

And the debugger *only* hits the line that throws the exception (although I've added a `try/catch` around the call to this method, and it doesn't catch this exception).

Finally, in Visual Studio's options, I chose "Enable .NET Framework source stepping," and `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is evaluating to false, confirming what the debugger has already told me.

Comment: @robg37 OK, so now you know none of us are crazy ;-) The next thing I need to know is if all of this code is within one project or if the MyUtility class is in a completely different project than your main web project.

Comment: @RussWilson I was a little worried about myself being crazy :-)  Anyway, this code is all within a single website (as in, not a web application).  The website is in a solution that contains another project - a console application.  The console application does have a MyUtility class as well (which includes the same method, among others), but it's in a separate namespace.

Comment: @robg37 Hmmm... so, if I understand you correctly, you're saying that you have actually made 2 MyUtility classes both with the same method.  Can you make sure that you haven't added a reference to the console application?  Also, when you step into the MyUtility.NotifyAdmin(...) method while debugging within visual studio, is it taking you to the correct class/method within the website's namespace and not the namespace of the console application?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77121/discussion-on-question-by-robg37-c-if-statement-evaluating-to-true-when-string).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what needs to be done in regards to answering this question, but as best I can tell, there's something screwy going on with the Visual Studio debugger, but it doesn't have any actual effect on my code.